# Which software is considered spam here?

Tags: discussion, spam

I suggested Movavi Screen Recorder as an answer to [this question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/83102/software-to-make-video-from-a-game/84977?noredirect=1#comment104465_84977). My answer was deleted as spam, although I use the software myself and didn't notice any viruses or other adware there. According to the moderator, Movavi marked my reply as spam. Does it mean that all Movavi software is considered spam here? Is there any other software that is considered spam? Is there a list of such software?

Comment: I don't think there is a "final list" of such – but Movavi.com definitely is in the range of those often spammed (i.e. used in spammy answers, self-promotion without disclosure etc). So while you indeed might use the software and be happy with it, the way it is often "promoted" is what we do not want at SE sites (btw, it's not just SR; Movavi had its "hits" on multiple SE sites with posts marked as spam).

Comment: Shade, as I said, I use the program myself, as do some other programs from Movavi, and they're not bad, even if they're not ideal. I really didn't suggest this as an advertisement or any other malicious intent. Although there is no list, it would be good for new users like me to be advised of such software not to suggest.

Comment: We cannot put up advices for everything – who would read that before their first post? #D Companies should be adviced not to send out people to spamvertize their products, which only sheds a bad light on them anyway, and we wouldn't have that issue ¯\_ (ツ)_/¯ // Sorry for you in this case. I saw your two answers and was already expecting something like this. I hope you understand our position, though. No bad intentions here. And thanks you've asked for clarification instead of just "assuming something"!

Comment: @Izzy But on every other SE site giving any software recomendation would be off topic, or am I mising something.

Comment: @Izzy So I'm not from any company. Is there a problem with my other answer?

Comment: The links in both your anwers contained some yandex part, which I have removed.

Comment: @crazymodder I didn't see a problem with it, no.

Comment: @Izzy What about Wondershare, is it spam too?

Comment: I'd say yes, But that might be subjective.

Comment: @Izzy Does it mean I can't suggest Wondershare as an answer either?

Comment: You'd risk having it flagged spam, yes, I cannot tell about their software, but their advertising is quite aggressive so answers linking to them could be seen as if the account posting it is one of their "spamvertizers".

Comment: @Izzy And if it gets flagged as spam, do I risk getting banned as a spamer?

Comment: If too many of your posts are marked spam, that risk does exist, yes.

Comment: @Izzy Is there a specific number, or is it a secret?

Comment: @Izzy And what about VSDC?